# Does the compiler optimise the parameters that does not change?

Tags: java, optimization, parameters

```
class X
{
    public static void func(int timesLeft, Object obj)
    {
        if (timesLeft-- == 0)
            return;

        System.out.println(obj);

        func(timesLeft, obj);
    }
}
```

In this code it's obvious that the parameter `timesLeft` changes, but `obj` is the same for all function calls. Does `obj` get passed and put on a stack frame for each call or does the compiler notice that it's the same object each time and applies some optimizations such that all the calls access the same location for the second parameter (`obj`) instead of each call having its own parameter?

---

**Edit:**

This example is just a simplified one. There are some situations where processing some data structure needs recursion. For example exploring graphs. If I want to apply dfs on a graph for example, I would want to keep track of visited nodes (maybe by using a `boolean[]`). Since this boolean array is specific to the function and isn't used elsewhere , it doesn't make sense to store it as a field or something. probably the best thing to do is to pass it to every call. So I was wondering does the compiler optimise something like that or not but with a simpler exmple.

Comment: No. Not even if you did `public static void func(int timesLeft, final Object obj)` -  the value of the `obj` reference must be passed on every stack frame you recurse. Also, Java does not have a tail-call optimization. Why on earth would you write this with recursion? Also, `func(-1, "Hello")` is going to blow up.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch There are some situations where processing some data structure needs recursion. For example exploring graphs. If I want to apply dfs on a graph for example, I would want to keep track of visited nodes (maybe by using a ``boolean[]``). Since this boolean array is specific to the function and isn't used elsewhere , it doesn't make sense to store it as a field or something. probably the best thing to do is to pass it to every call. So I was wondering does the compiler optimise something like that or not but with a simpler exmple.

Comment: I understood your question. Unfortunately, as I already said, the answer is no. The compiler does **not** perform the optimization you're asking about. Nor does it perform a tail-call optimization.

Comment: The JVM doesn't have any instructions to reach down into lower stack frames, so there can't be any such optimization. @ElliottFrisch has nowhere suggested that recursion itself is never necessary.